# Replacement Character appearing in my colored output

Tags: java, console, replit

I've got a strange problem I can't seem to diagnose effectively. I wanted a simple tool that could take a BufferedImage and print it to a console for my class. In relpit, the console's font uses perfect 2-1 characters, so to print a pixel, you only need to print two spaces with a certain background color.

This works well, but the pixels are bigger than they need to be. If you use a special character called an upper half-block, you can cut pixel size down from 2-2 to 1-1, quadrupling the density and rendering it easy to use.

This is almost amazing, but a problem does show up (as it usually does when I open the character map). Sometimes the half-block does not print, and I am left with two replacement characters. This does not happen when coloring is absent or when I use Ascii characters instead, and to make it worse, the error is apparently random, with lighting only sometimes striking the same position twice.

I tried to set this up in eclipse to see if I could see an improvement, but the console won't support this coloring method I know or even let me type the upper half block (I'm sure there's an escape sequence for it, but I'm not familiar).

I'll summarize my approach here I'm using these for coloring:

```
private static String getRGBBackground(int r, int g, int b) {
    return "\u001B[48;2;" + r + ";" + g + ";" + b + "m";
}
private static String getRGBForeground(int r, int g, int b) {
    return "\u001B[38;2;" + r + ";" + g + ";" + b + "m";
}
```

This is the print statement itself:

```
public void print (BufferedImage image) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        for (int r = 0; r < image.getHeight(); r+=2) {
            for (int c = 0; c < image.getWidth(); c++) {
                
                int color = image.getRGB(c,r);
                color <<= 8;
                color >>>= 8;
                int blu = (color >>  0) % 256;
                int grn = (color >>  8) % 256;
                int red = (color >> 16) % 256;
                
                str.append(getRGBForeground(red,grn,blu));

                if ((r+1) < image.getHeight()) {
                    color = image.getRGB(c,r+1);
                    color <<= 8;
                    color >>>= 8;
                    blu = (color >>  0) % 256;
                    grn = (color >>  8) % 256;
                    red = (color >> 16) % 256;
                    str.append(getRGBBackground(red,grn,blu));
                }

                str.append("▀");
            }
            str.append("\u001b[0m\n");
        }

        out.println(str);
    }
```

[image: Sample program output]

If anyone has any tips to address the replacement character or even just closer that these things don't ever work, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just tried putting the output into a string, and if I print that multiple times it is still randomly flawed, leading me to believe this is a problem of the actual printing process, which is sad, but maybe there is another way to print the same character, configure the console to work, or accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I just tried your code with several different images, and I didn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://replit.com/@ThomasHolt3/ImageRender#Main.java